# compare lines with a pattern in two files

Tags: perl

lets take an example

If my data set is like this. 
LOG 1 (x.log) contains

```
INFO @1102266 PHResourceLayer_Z4: mti_clk_chk:################ start of test ################ ; T=1102266
INFO @1102334 PHResourceLayer_Z4: mti_clk_chk:Checking the period of MTI, MTI10 clk from SV; T=1102334
```

LOG 2 (y.log) contains

```
UVM_INFO @1092507 reporter Z4_COREA: mti_clk_chk: ################ start of test ################ ; T=1092507
UVM_INFO @1092563 reporter Z4_COREA: mti_clk_chk: Checking the period of MTI, MTI10 clk from SV; T=1092563
```

Then for first line I have to check

```
################ start of test ################ ; T=1102266
```

and

```
################ start of test ################ ; T=1092507
```

as value of T are not same so it should give these details in output file stating the details are not matching.

Similarily for line 2 we have to match

```
Checking the period of MTI, MTI10 clk from SV; T=1102334
```

and

```
Checking the period of MTI, MTI10 clk from SV; T=1092563
```

Here also values of T are not matching so pass it to output file.

I have to compare details line by line in two log files having certain keyword `mti_clk_chk`. Till now I'm able to parse it line by line with required keyword from both files into a third file. Now I want to compare the data present after the keyword following colon(`:`) and in output file I have to print the mismatched lines from first data-set on comparing it with second data-set and number of lines in second data set that are not present in first data-set. Data after parsing two log files is given below. Please help me out how to compare details provided in each line between two set of data.

```perl
open(FILE, "<x.log");
my @array = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

open(FILE, "<y.log");
my @array1 = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

open(FILE, ">>file.txt");
my @array2 = <FILE>;
foreach $_ (@array & @array1) {
         @array2 = grep {$_ =~ "mti_clk_chk:"} (@array);
                  print FILE "@array2";
          print FILE "\n \n \n";

         @array2 = grep {$_ =~ "mti_clk_chk:"} (@array1);
                  print FILE "@array2";
                  close(FILE);
exit;
}
```

Sample data in file.txt after parsing two input logs (x.log and y.log)

```
INFO @576892 mti_clk_chk: run_stimulus called; T=576892
INFO @1102266 PHResourceLayer_Z4: mti_clk_chk:################ start of test ################ ; T=1102266
INFO @1102334 PHResourceLayer_Z4: mti_clk_chk:Checking the period of MTI, MTI10 clk from SV; T=1102334
INFO @1102372 mti_clk_chk: Checking period of MTI CLk; T=1102372
INFO @1102377 mti_clk_chk: Period value of MTI Clock: 3.125000 ns; T=1102377
INFO @1102377 mti_clk_chk: MTI Clock is being generated correctly ; T=1102377
INFO @1102377 mti_clk_chk: Checking period of MTI10 CLk; T=1102377
INFO @1102418 mti_clk_chk: Period value of MTI10 Clock: 31.250000 ns; T=1102418
INFO @1102418 mti_clk_chk: MTI10 Clock is being generated correctly ; T=1102418
INFO @1102717 PHResourceLayer_Z4: mti_clk_chk: All clock period Checking done; T=1102717
INFO @1148661 mti_clk_chk: C-Code exit execution. code=<aa>; T=1148661
INFO @1148661 mti_clk_chk: ************************ SV END******************** ; T=1148661

UVM_INFO @0 reporter testbench.top_level_module.\mti_clk_chk::main : MTI_CLK_CHK_STIM Started .....; T=0
UVM_INFO @0 reporter testbench.top_level_module.\mti_clk_chk::main : run_stimulus called; T=0
UVM_INFO @1092507 reporter Z4_COREA: mti_clk_chk: ################ start of test ################ ; T=1092507
UVM_INFO @1092563 reporter Z4_COREA: mti_clk_chk: Checking the period of MTI, MTI10 clk from SV; T=1092563
UVM_INFO @1092598 reporter testbench.top_level_module.\mti_clk_chk::main : Checking period of MTI CLk; T=1092598
UVM_INFO @1092605 /proj/rru2_verif/usr/Tilak/SV_UVM/testbench/data_ipdss/v_ms_mti_stim_vip/testbench/classes_v/mti_clk_chk.sv(147) uvm_test_top.default_env.default_sequencer100@@mti_clk_chk mti_clk_chk:INFO: Period value of MTI Clock: 3.125000 ns; T=1092605
UVM_INFO @1092605 reporter testbench.top_level_module.\mti_clk_chk::main : MTI Clock is being generated correctly ; T=1092605
UVM_INFO @1092605 reporter testbench.top_level_module.\mti_clk_chk::main : Checking period of MTI10 CLk; T=1092605
UVM_INFO @1092655 /proj/rru2_verif/usr/Tilak/SV_UVM/testbench/data_ipdss/v_ms_mti_stim_vip/testbench/classes_v/mti_clk_chk.sv(165) uvm_test_top.default_env.default_sequencer100@@mti_clk_chk mti_clk_chk:INFO: Period value of MTI10 Clock: 31.250000 ns; T=1092655
UVM_INFO @1092655 reporter testbench.top_level_module.\mti_clk_chk::main : MTI10 Clock is being generated correctly ; T=1092655
UVM_INFO @1092850 reporter Z4_COREA: mti_clk_chk: All clock period Checking done; T=1092850
UVM_INFO @1092886 /proj/rru2_verif/usr/Tilak/SV_UVM/testbench/data_ipdss/v_ms_mti_stim_vip/testbench/classes_v/mti_clk_chk.sv(186) uvm_test_top.default_env.default_sequencer100@@mti_clk_chk mti_clk_chk:INFO: ************************ SV END******************** ; T=1092886
```

Comment: I edited your question to make the inputs & outputs more readable. Please check if I haven't inadvertently removed some information that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your input data correctly you want

- read lines from file 1

  - filter the lines that contain the filter keyword `mti_clk_chk:`
  - store everything after the keyword for comparison
- same with file 2
- print out lines from file 1 whose comparison string can't be found in file 2
- vice versa for file 2

The proposed solution for your question:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;
use feature qw(say);

die "usage: $0 <log1> <log2>\n"
    if @ARGV < 2;
my($log1, $log2) = @ARGV;

# log file extractor function
sub extractor($) {
    my($file) = @_;
    my %lines;
    my @order;

    # Parse log file contents
    open(my $fh, '<', $file);
    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        if (my($key) = /mti_clk_chk:\s*(.+)$/) {
            die "duplicate log line '$_' detected at ${file}:$.!\n"
                if exists $lines{$key};
            $lines{$key} = $_;
            push(@order, $key);
        }
    }
    close($fh);

    return((\%lines, \@order));
}

# parse log files
my($lines_log1, $order_log1) = extractor($log1);
my($lines_log2, $order_log2) = extractor($log2);

# lines in log1 but not in log2
say foreach (
    map  { $lines_log1->{$_} }
    grep { ! exists $lines_log2->{$_} }
    @{ $order_log1 }
);

# separator in output
say "";

# lines in log2 but not in log1
say foreach (
    map  { $lines_log2->{$_} }
    grep { ! exists $lines_log1->{$_} }
    @{ $order_log2 }
);

exit 0;
```

Test run with the two lines you have given as example. I added some junk at the start and the end to make sure it does not end up in the desired output.

```
$ cat dummy1.txt
test1
INFO @1102266 PHResourceLayer_Z4: mti_clk_chk:################ start of test ################ ; T=1102266
INFO @1102334 PHResourceLayer_Z4: mti_clk_chk:Checking the period of MTI, MTI10 clk from SV; T=1102334
test1

$ cat dummy2.txt
test2
UVM_INFO @1092507 reporter Z4_COREA: mti_clk_chk: ################ start of test ################ ; T=1092507
UVM_INFO @1092563 reporter Z4_COREA: mti_clk_chk: Checking the period of MTI, MTI10 clk from SV; T=1092563
test2

$ perl dummy.pl dummy1.txt dummy2.txt
INFO @1102266 PHResourceLayer_Z4: mti_clk_chk:################ start of test ################ ; T=1102266
INFO @1102334 PHResourceLayer_Z4: mti_clk_chk:Checking the period of MTI, MTI10 clk from SV; T=1102334

UVM_INFO @1092507 reporter Z4_COREA: mti_clk_chk: ################ start of test ################ ; T=1092507
UVM_INFO @1092563 reporter Z4_COREA: mti_clk_chk: Checking the period of MTI, MTI10 clk from SV; T=1092563
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @StefanBecker, your code is working fine but I need to print the data in a separate output file and it should be the same data that we are comparing (after the keyword) not the complete line.

Secondly one thing more for file 1: Print the data not matching with file 2 but while comparing for file 2 I need just number of instances when data is not matching (number of lines)

Comment: (a) just use `perl script.pl log1.txt log2.txt >output.txt`, (b) your example indicates that the output file should contain whole lines, not the comparison string, (c) again, your example indicates to print not-found lines from log1 in log2, then not-found lines from log2 in log1. Answers can only be based on what input, problem description and expected output are presented in the question.

Comment: Please up-vote and accept the answer if it fulfills the original question. What you describe in your comment sounds like something you can figure out yourself given the code in my answer, i.e. IMHO it doesn't warrant another question.

Comment: perl script.pl log1.txt log2.txt >output.txt
This is not working fine, please help me out in printing comparison string not the whole line in a separate output file.

Comment: Can you be more specific "what is not working"? Is there an error message? `>output.txt` redirects the standard output from the perl script into the file, i.e. everything the script prints goes into that file. This should work with every command line tool on any OS. Using the file names from your question `perl script.pl x.log y.log >file.txt` with the Perl code stored in `script.pl`