# Compare two log files line by line and print difference

Tags: perl

I have to compare two different log files line by line (in each line data between two symbols (`:` and `;`) is to be checked) and print all lines of log 1 that are not in log 2. I have used this approach but the result is not correct.

Content in log1:

```
INFO @0 digrf_0_drv: Constructing a digrf Driver: digrf_0_drv; T=0
INFO @648647 mti_disable_fuse_cov_inst: run_stimulus called; T=648647
INFO @1549325 mti_disable_fuse_cov_inst:  CHECKING MTI DISABLE FUSE CONNECTED TO flash_mti_en; T=1549325
INFO @1549325 mti_disable_fuse_cov_inst: MTI_DISABLE fuse is correctly asserted ; T=1549325
```

Content in log 2:

```
UVM_INFO @1381068 mti_disable_fuse_cov [mti_disable_fuse_cov:INFO]:  CHECKING MTI DISABLE FUSE CONNECTED TO flash_mti_en; T=1381068
UVM_INFO @1381068 mti_disable_fuse_cov [mti_disable_fuse_cov:INFO]: MTI_DISABLE fuse is correctly asserted ; T=1381068
UVM_INFO @1381068 reporter [Z7_COREB]: V FLAG_CLEAR: Clearing flag 1; T=1381068
UVM_INFO @1381068 reporter [Z4_COREA]: V FLAG_SET: Setting flag 2; T=1381068
```

Expected output:

```
Constructing a digrf Driver: digrf_0_drv
run_stimulus called
```

Now my current code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
#use 5.012;

my $filename1 = 'log2';
my %a_links;

open(FILE, $filename1) or die "Could not read from $filename1, program halting.";
while(<FILE>)
{
    chomp;
    my @fields1 = split(/[:;]/, $_);
    $a_links{$fields1[1]} = undef;

}
close FILE;

my $filename2 = 'log1';
my @fields;
open(FILE, $filename2) or die "Could not read from $filename2, program halting.";
while(<FILE>)
{
    chomp;
    @fields = split(/[:;]/, $_);
    next if exists $a_links{$fields[1]}; 
    print "$fields[1] \n";
}

close FILE;
```

**EDIT**
If two or more lines have same set of info in log 1 then print just single line in output.
Log 1

```
INFO @0 digrf_0_drv: Constructing a digrf Driver: digrf_0_drv; T=0
INFO @603845 mcPWM_CYC: ----- SV is waiting for FLAG 4  -----; T=603845
INFO @1116033 mcPWM_CYC: ----- SV is waiting for FLAG 0  -----; T=1116033
INFO @1145215 mcPWM_CYC: ----- Flag 0 OK SV STARTED  -----; T=1145215
INFO @1145215 mcPWM_CYC: PORT STIM started !!!; T=1145215
INFO @1145287 mcPWM_CYC: ----- SV is waiting for FLAG 2  -----; T=1145287
INFO @1146281 mcPWM_CYC: ----- Flag 0 OK : SV STARTED  -----; T=1146281
INFO @1146281 mcPWM_CYC: PORT STIM started !!!; T=1146281
INFO @1190554 mcPWM_CYC: C-Code exit execution. code=<aa>; T=1190554
INFO @1190554 mti_lane1_bw_mon: total bytes = 0, at time = 1190554; T=1190554
INFO @1190554 mti_lane1_bw_mon: time window = 0, at time = 1190554; T=1190554
INFO @1190554 mti_lane1_bw_mon: BW in Mbps = 0, at time = 1190554; T=1190554
INFO @1190554 mti_lane2_bw_mon: total bytes = 0, at time = 1190554; T=1190554
INFO @1190554 mti_lane2_bw_mon: time window = 0, at time = 1190554; T=1190554
INFO @1190554 mti_lane2_bw_mon: BW in Mbps = 0, at time = 1190554; T=1190554
INFO @1190554 mti_lane3_bw_mon: total bytes = 0, at time = 1190554; T=1190554
INFO @1190554 mti_lane3_bw_mon: time window = 0, at time = 1190554; T=1190554
INFO @1190554 mti_lane3_bw_mon: BW in Mbps = 0, at time = 1190554; T=1190554
INFO @1190554 mti_lane4_bw_mon: total bytes = 0, at time = 1190554; T=1190554
INFO @1190554 mti_lane4_bw_mon: time window = 0, at time = 1190554; T=1190554
INFO @1190554 mti_lane4_bw_mon: BW in Mbps = 0, at time = 1190554; T=1190554
INFO @1190554 mti_lane5_bw_mon: total bytes = 0, at time = 1190554; T=1190554
INFO @1190554 mti_lane5_bw_mon: time window = 0, at time = 1190554; T=1190554
INFO @1190554 mti_lane5_bw_mon: BW in Mbps = 0, at time = 1190554; T=1190554
INFO: Report(s) of this encapsulation run can be found under:
```

Log2:

```
UVM_INFO @1353514 reporter [Z7_COREA]: mcPWM0_ExtSig: *** START Syncronization with Verilog Stimulus ***; T=1353514
UVM_INFO @1353578 reporter [Z7_COREA]: C FLAG_SET: Setting flag 0; T=1353578
UVM_INFO @1353578 reporter [Z7_COREA]: V FLAG_WAIT: Received flag 0; T=1353578
UVM_INFO @1353578 reporter [testbench.top_level_module.\mcPWM_CYC::main ]: ----- Flag 0 OK SV STARTED  -----; T=1353578
UVM_INFO @1353578 reporter [testbench.top_level_module.\mcPWM_CYC::main ]: PORT STIM started !!!; T=1353578
UVM_INFO @1353642 reporter [Z7_COREA]: C FLAG_WAIT: Checking flag 1, status is 0; T=1353642
UVM_INFO @1353650 reporter [Z7_COREA]: V FLAG_SET: Setting flag 1; T=1353650
UVM_INFO @1353650 reporter [testbench.top_level_module.\mcPWM_CYC::main ]: ----- SV is waiting for FLAG 2  -----; T=1353650
UVM_INFO @1353650 reporter [Z4_COREA]: V FLAG_WAIT: Checking flag 2, status is 0; T=1353650
UVM_INFO @1353743 reporter [Z7_COREA]: C FLAG_WAIT: Checking flag 1, status is 1; T=1353743
UVM_INFO @1354063 reporter [Z7_COREA]: REM16: A=fbc00086 R=0007 E=0007 M=ffff; T=1354063
UVM_INFO @1354336 reporter [Z7_COREA]: REM16: A=fbc00080 R=048e E=048e M=ffff; T=1354336
UVM_INFO @1354532 reporter [Z7_COREA]: W16: A=fbc00080 W=008d; T=1354532
UVM_INFO @1354597 reporter [Z7_COREA]: C FLAG_SET: Setting flag 2; T=1354597
UVM_INFO @1354597 reporter [Z7_COREA]: V FLAG_WAIT: Received flag 2; T=1354597
UVM_INFO @1354597 reporter [testbench.top_level_module.\mcPWM_CYC::main ]: ----- Flag 0 OK SV STARTED  -----; T=1354597
UVM_INFO @1354597 reporter [testbench.top_level_module.\mcPWM_CYC::main ]: PORT STIM started !!!; T=1354597
UVM_INFO @1354597 reporter [Z7_COREA]: V FLAG_WAIT: Received flag 2; T=1354597
UVM_INFO @1354597 reporter [Z7_COREA]: V FLAG_WAIT: Checking flag 2, status is 1; T=1354597
UVM_INFO @1354661 reporter [Z7_COREA]: C FLAG_WAIT: Checking flag 2, status is 1; T=1354661
UVM_INFO @1354741 reporter [Z7_COREA]: V FLAG_CLEAR: Clearing flag 2; T=1354741
UVM_INFO @1354741 reporter [Z4_COREA]: V FLAG_SET: Setting flag 5; T=1354741
UVM_INFO @1354741 reporter [Z7_COREA]: V FLAG_WAIT: Received flag 2; T=1354741
```

Expected Output:

```
Constructing a digrf Driver: digrf_0_drv
----- SV is waiting for FLAG 4  -----
----- SV is waiting for FLAG 0  -----
C-Code exit execution. code=<aa>
total bytes = 0, at time = 1190554
time window = 0, at time = 1190554
BW in Mbps = 0, at time = 1190554 
Report(s) of this encapsulation run can be found under
```

Output coming with EDIT2 :

```
Constructing a digrf Driver
----- SV is waiting for FLAG 4  -----
----- SV is waiting for FLAG 0  -----
----- Flag 0 OK SV STARTED  -----
PORT STIM started !!!
----- SV is waiting for FLAG 2  -----
----- Flag 0 OK
PORT STIM started !!!
C-Code exit execution. code=<aa>
total bytes = 0, at time = 1190554
time window = 0, at time = 1190554
BW in Mbps = 0, at time = 1190554
Report(s) of this encapsulation run can be found under
```

Output coming with EDIT3 :

```
Constructing a digrf Driver
----- Flag 0 OK
C-Code exit execution. code=<aa>
total bytes = 0, at time = 1190554
time window = 0, at time = 1190554
BW in Mbps = 0, at time = 1190554
Report(s) of this encapsulation run can be found under
```

Comment: What is the code doing now? Can you please [edit] and show your current output as well?

Comment: Duplicate of your earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763580/compare-lines-with-a-pattern-in-two-files)

Comment: Have you considered using [diff(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command line perl

```
perl -F"/[:;]/" -lane ' $i=$ARGV eq "log1.txt" ? 1 : 2;$F[$i]=~s/^\s*|\s*$//g; 
     $kv{$F[$i]}=$ARGV ; END { for(keys %kv) { print "$_" if $kv{$_} eq "log1.txt" } } '
```

with your given inputs:

```
$ cat log1.txt
INFO @0 digrf_0_drv: Constructing a digrf Driver: digrf_0_drv; T=0
INFO @648647 mti_disable_fuse_cov_inst: run_stimulus called; T=648647
INFO @1549325 mti_disable_fuse_cov_inst:  CHECKING MTI DISABLE FUSE CONNECTED TO flash_mti_en; T=1549325
INFO @1549325 mti_disable_fuse_cov_inst: MTI_DISABLE fuse is correctly asserted ; T=1549325

$ cat log2.txt
UVM_INFO @1381068 mti_disable_fuse_cov [mti_disable_fuse_cov:INFO]:  CHECKING MTI DISABLE FUSE CONNECTED TO flash_mti_en; T=1381068
UVM_INFO @1381068 mti_disable_fuse_cov [mti_disable_fuse_cov:INFO]: MTI_DISABLE fuse is correctly asserted ; T=1381068
UVM_INFO @1381068 reporter [Z7_COREB]: V FLAG_CLEAR: Clearing flag 1; T=1381068
UVM_INFO @1381068 reporter [Z4_COREA]: V FLAG_SET: Setting flag 2; T=1381068

$ perl -F"/[:;]/" -lane ' $i=$ARGV eq "log1.txt" ? 1 : 2;$F[$i]=~s/^\s*|\s*$//g; 
$kv{$F[$i]}=$ARGV ; END { for(keys %kv) { print "$_" if $kv{$_} eq "log1.txt" } } ' log1.txt log2.txt
Constructing a digrf Driver
run_stimulus called

$
```

**EDIT:**

To print it in order, use

```
perl -F"/[:;]/" -lane ' $i=$ARGV eq "log1.txt" ? 1 : 2;$F[$i]=~s/^\s*|\s*$//g;
$kv{$F[$i]}=$ARGV ;push(@f,$F[$i]) ; END { for(@f) { print "$_" if $kv{$_} eq "log1.txt" } } ' log1.txt log2.txt
```

**EDIT2:**

```
 perl -F"/[:;]/" -lane ' $i=$ARGV eq "log1.txt" ? 1 : 2;$F[$i]=~s/^\s*|\s*$//g;
$kv{$F[$i]}=$ARGV ;push(@f,$F[$i]) ; END { for(@f) { print "$_" if $kv{$_} eq "log1.txt" } } ' log1.txt log2.txt | perl -0777 -pe ' s/(^total.*)\1//gms '
```

**EDIT3**

```
 perl -F"/[:;]/" -lane ' $i=$ARGV eq "log1.txt" ? 1 : $#F-1; $F[$i]=~s/^\s*|\s*$//g;
$kv{$F[$i]}=$ARGV ;push(@f,$F[$i]) ; END { for(@f) { print "$_" if $kv{$_} eq "log1.txt" } } ' log1.txt log2.txt | perl -0777 -pe ' s/(^total.*)\1//gms '
```

***EDIT4:***

This solution is entirely different to meet the expected output

```
$ perl -lne ' s!:\s+(.+?)\s*(;|:$)!$x=$1;$x=~s/: //g;$kv{$x}=$ARGV!e;push(@f,$x); END { for(@f) { print "$_" if $kv{$_} eq "log1.txt" } } ' log1.txt log2.txt | perl -0777 -pe ' s/(^total.*)*(?=\1)//gms'
Constructing a digrf Driverdigrf_0_drv
----- SV is waiting for FLAG 4  -----
----- SV is waiting for FLAG 0  -----
C-Code exit execution. code=<aa>
total bytes = 0, at time = 1190554
time window = 0, at time = 1190554
BW in Mbps = 0, at time = 1190554
Report(s) of this encapsulation run can be found under

$
```

Things to note:

```
----- Flag 0 OK : SV STARTED  -----  => log1.txt
----- Flag 0 OK SV STARTED  -----    => log2.txt
```

The above 2 lines are entirely different and so I have to remove ": " during the substitution process to match and eliminate them to get the required output

The last line in log1.txt

```
INFO: Report(s) of this encapsulation run can be found under:
```

doesn't have semicolon, so I adjusted with `|:$` in the regex match.

Hope this helps

Comment: your command is not printing log1 in order as it contains about 20-30 lines all lines are printing improperly

Comment: so you want the output in order ?..let me work on it

Comment: could you please check the solution in the ````EDIT```` section of the answer?>

Comment: Thanks a lot @stack0114106 for your timely help but now i'm facing one more problem, this command doesn't compare digits and special characters (like # @ $ etc.) otherwise for strings having only alphabets its working fine, can you please solve this issue also?

Comment: It will work for all cases.. I'm just trimming.. could you please share samples where it is not working?

Comment: pls check the updated log files in the question section and the expected output is also given. Please help me out.

Comment: the new output is not following a pattern... one way we could eliminate those duplicates is shown in EDIT2 - just pipe it to another perl command..

Comment: as you can see updated output i'm getting in the question, the lines that got matched in both logs it shouldn't come in output, please have a look.

Comment: can you please help me out in getting the desired output by some other approach...I want to compare data of every line (data starting from first colon to appearance of a semicolon) irrespective whether it is a set of alphabet, numbers or special characters.

Comment: check my EDIT4.. entirely a new solution.. hope it helps!